# How to adapt script tag to Angular?

Tags: javascript, angular

On my old website, I have had some problems with some bad guys, who have tried to clone my site.
Now I try to pass the application to Angular7.

One of the measures that I have implemented in the old page, to end the attempts to clone, **has been using a `.js` code to check the hostname from the header.**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
if(!['mysite.com','testsite.com'].includes(window.location.hostname)){
            window.location.href = 'https://google.com'; 
}
</script>
```

**Can someone tell me how I can convert (rewrite, adapt) this Javascript code so that it can be used in Angular?**

I want to use this code (if possible) in the source code, so it can be compiled after the run - `npm run build` - so that it stays integrated in `main.js` of my website.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your index.html

add this code

#### example

> src/app/index.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Stackoverflow</title>
  <base href="/">

  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
</head>
<body>
  <app-root></app-root>

  <script type="text/javascript">
  if(!['mysite.com','testsite.com'].includes(window.location.hostname)){
            window.location.href = 'https://google.com'; 
  }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

ok

Comment: Thanks George, but I want to add this under source code of my app (if is possible) so I need to be integrated in main.js (after npm run build) - This is to make it more difficult to jump, or eliminate this code, in case someone else tries to clone again my site

Comment: @ivan please Upvote my answer if I helped you. yes, you can add this and you will have this on the final bundle.